# MongoDB findOne transactions in Promise.all occur "NoSuchTransaction"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

MongoDB: 4.4

Nodejs driver: 3.6.6

I try to run findOne queries at same time. so i use Promise.all. but error was occur as below.

as i know read query don't compete race condition unlike modification query. is there a write conflict in find query?
if right, why??

i can handle the situation now by not using Promise.all, but I want to know the exact cause.

```
const session = Connection.client.startSession();

try {
    session.startTransaction();
    const result = await Promise.all([
        Connection.db.collection("movies").findOne(
            {
                genres: { $in: ["Drama"] },
            },
            { session }
        ),
        Connection.db.collection("movies").findOne(
          {
            genres: { $in: ["Fantasy"] },
          },
          { session }
        ),
        Connection.db.collection("movies").findOne(
          {
            genres: { $in: ["Crime"] },
          },
          { session }
        ),
  ]);
  await session.commitTransaction();
  res.status(200).send(result);
} catch (error) {
      console.log(error);

      await session.abortTransaction();
      res.status(500).send(error.message);
} finally {
      session.endSession();
}
```

----- error message -----

```
MongoError: Given transaction number 3 does not match any in-progress transactions. The active transaction number is 2
at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/ian/Workspace/my/mongodb-transaction-test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:451:61)
at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
at processMessage (/Users/ian/Workspace/my/mongodb-transaction-test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:451:10)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/ian/Workspace/my/mongodb-transaction-test/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:620:15)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)

{ operationTime: Timestamp \{ _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 5012, high_: 1619623035 }
,
ok: 0,
code: 251,
codeName: 'NoSuchTransaction',
'$clusterTime':

{ clusterTime: Timestamp \{ _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 5012, high_: 1619623035 }
,
signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
},
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'TransientTransactionError' }
}
```

Comment: Use withTransaction, startTransaction is not meant for this use case. What produces the error exactly?

Comment: what difference withTransaction with startTransaction?

Comment: Feel free to ask that as a separate question.